# Why do I have '%' at the end of my print statement?

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code, printing, zsh

I am coding java in VScode, and for some reason I am getting a '%' at the end of my print line. I don't know wether it's a VS code thing or if it's something else.

I am on a Mac if that changes anything and my terminal is zsh.

[[image]

Comment: you forgot to put new line symbol `\n` at the end of the string

Comment: since using a `printf`, it is recommended to use `%n` instead of `\n` (it will result in the platform-specific line separator being output - e.g. `\r\n` for windows)

Comment: This can be configured. I also find the default (%) a bit confusing, and I have set in my .zshrc `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=⁇` (where the ?? actually is the character for [unicode code point 2047](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2047)).

Answer (score 2):

That is a symbol generated by `zsh` as an indicator. It indicates: There is no actual newline at the end of this statement, but, for reasons, I'm showing you this as a line anyhow. It's not a %, because its rendered 'inverse' (it's black on white).

The fix is simply to add `\n` to the end of your string. `printf` doesn't add a newline on its own.

Comment: Right, it just brings the % to the next line making it disappear. but why is it there? I have run this code using different IDE's and it only appears tin VScode

Comment: @MarcusHauen-Limkilde Presumably because other IDEs just hook themselves directly up to the JVM process you ran, whereas VSCode either [A] instead launches zsh, connecting zsh's standard in and standard out to the VSCode view, and then having that zsh launch the JVM. It's zsh printing that %. or [B] VSCode's terminal adopted the zsh convention of printing an inverted % to indicate 'no newline here', and other IDEs do not do that.